# Pointless unit test

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, unit-testing

I have a baseService class that most of my services inherit from, which looks like this.

```
public abstract class BaseService<T> : IBaseService<T>
    where T : class, IBaseEntity
{
    protected IDataContext _context;
    protected IValidator<T> _validator = null;

    protected BaseService(IDataContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    protected BaseService(IDataContext context, IValidator<T> validator)
        : this(context)
    {
        _validator = validator;
    }

    public virtual async Task<ICollection<T>> GetAllAsync()
    {
        return await _context.Set<T>().ToListAsync();
    }

    public virtual Task<T> GetAsync(long id)
    {
        return _context.Set<T>().Where(e => e.Id == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }

    public virtual Task<ValidationResult> ValidateAsync(T t)
    {
        if (_validator == null) throw new MissingFieldException("Validator does not exist for class " + t.GetType().ToString() + ". override method if no validation needed");
        return _validator.ValidateAsync(t);
    }

    public virtual async Task<int> AddAsync(T t)
    {
        var results = await ValidateAsync(t);

        if (!results.IsValid) {
            throw new ValidationException(results.Errors);
        }

        if (_context.GetState(t) == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            _context.Set<T>().Add(t);
            _context.SetState(t, EntityState.Added);
        }

        return await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public virtual async Task<int> UpdateAsync(T updated)
    {
        var results = await ValidateAsync(updated);

        if (!results.IsValid)
        {
            throw new ValidationException(results.Errors);
        }

        if (_context.GetState(updated) == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            _context.SetState(updated, EntityState.Modified);
        }

        return await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public virtual Task<int> DeleteAsync(T t)
    {
        _context.SetState(t, EntityState.Deleted);

        return _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

Am i right in thinking that it is pointless to unit test this in every single one of my classes that implements this service?  But instead, test the functionality for each test in my integration testing?

Comment: Its hard to say really. I would test the methods that aren't simply fascades around LINQ. Aseerting things such as thrown exceptions and entity states. The rest is pointless .. you'll be basically testing LINQ after that.

Comment: Since the methods are virtual, I'll test them, because who know when some derived class overrides it, but failed to throw when validation failed, or failed to call `ValidateAsync` etc. If not virtual, you can test only one derived class which will cover all the methods basically.

Comment: I personally would test them all. To simplify that task you could either create a base class for each fixture, with a template method factory method for creating the concrete implementation of the SUT, the tests for the base class public methods or write something like an AutoFixture idiom, basically a class that would test the base class.

Comment: And what is the view of writing this as a BaseUnitTest and inheriting unit test from that base one to test this functionality?  Just seems such a waste of time writing the same tests over and over again.

Comment: Are you actually overriding any of these methods? Or extend since it seems to wrap all CRUD stuff already. If not, why make it abstract at all.

Comment: Yes sometimes i override the method as have to do something before it adds or updates etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid that decision if you choose [composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance), that is, instead of your services inheriting from BaseService, you create them as having IBaseService as a dependency, for example

```
public class MyService 
{
  private readonly IBaseService<SomeBaseIdentity> _service;

  public MyService(IBaseService<SomeBaseIdentity> service)
  {
    _service = service;
  }

  //.... methods that use _service
}
```

This way you can test MyService using an isolation framework (Rhino Mocks, Moq, etc) without worrying about the actual implementation of IBaseService.

A lot has been written about this topic of choosing composition over inheritance. The great majority of which implies that it is a superior approach (mainly because it is more flexible, i.e. you can swap implementations if you use composition, whereas if you use inheritance all your derived classes are tied to the base class in the sense that changes to the base class affect all derived classes), to the point of the Java language creator saying that if he could, he would [disallow it in Java](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073649/core-java/why-extends-is-evil.html).

Comment: I think i am going to try this as, most of the time i would like to use the AddAsync and other functions in the base class, so seems pointless to unit test the "call".  But in other classes where i override the method, i would want to unit test it.  Maybe composition would be better suited here.

Comment: How would u then write a unit test for myservice and say another service called MyService2 usinh composition instead of inhertiance?

Comment: I would write a unit test for each service, however I'd use a stub/mock of IBaseService (these names make this confusing, think of IBaseService as a dependency, for example IRepository). If you are unfamiliar with this, [check this out](https://blinkingcaret.wordpress.com/2012/11/20/interaction-testing-fakes-mocks-and-stubs/).

Comment: Since you suggested it, i have taken your advice.  Is this correct? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29653153/composition-migrating-from-inheritance Seems to compile ok, but simple injector now throws errors for injecting the IEntityBaseService<T>,  i am guessing because it is generic

Comment: Would you mind taking a look at this? http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/86974/using-composition-instead-of-inheritance